# BigQuery - Streaming Inserts - Schema Update Options

Tags: google-bigquery

Using the BQ job loading mechanism (i.e not streaming insert), there is options to enable dynamic schema evolution using the setting / options below within the job request:

configuration.load.schemaUpdateOptions[]

ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION: allow adding a nullable field to the schema. ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION: allow relaxing a required field in the original schema to nullable.

this is super powerful for easily allowing backward compat changes.  We are looking to move to the streaming inserts model, but seems this feature is not supportred?

Ive had a look at the Table API for insert (aka 'streaming inserts), but appears this is not an option using this method?

Have I missed this?  If not (gutted), is it on the roadmap?

Thanks! :)

Comment: and TableData API I should say too.....

Comment: ...if it cant, if there is an alternate way to achieve the same please do let me know.

Comment: @elliott-brossard thoughts on this?  Looking at switching to streaming inserts soon so just evaluating differences / gaps - dynamic schema updates seems missing (or am I missing something?) Cheers! :)

Comment: From what I know  - You can only @reply to users who have already left a comment, or edited the post. See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). So you cannot just call out or invite someone to your post if he/she not in your post already. Thought you might want to know this :o)

Comment: OK thanks Mikhail I didnt know appreciate the info.